# discord.py - 'list' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, discord.py

im trying to delete the bottom role of the server, but it keeps giving me that error on the tittle
Please help me

Updated with all the code

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='e!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('client ready' + '\n')

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def del_channel(ctx, arg1):
    ch = []
    n = -1
    sv = [discord.utils.get([x for x in client.servers], id=arg1)]
    for server in sv:
        for channel in server.channels:
            ch.append(channel)
    while True:
        try:
            n=n+1
            if n == 2:
                break
            val = ch[n]
            await client.delete_channel(val)
            print("Deleted Channel: " + str(val))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def del_roles(ctx, arg1, role = discord.Role):
    rl = []
    n = -1
    sv = [discord.utils.get([x for x in client.servers], id=arg1)]
    for server in sv:
        for role in server.roles:
            rl.append(role)
    while True:
        try:
            n=n+1
            if n == 2:
                break
            val = rl[n]
            await client.delete_role(sv, role=val)
            print("Deleted Role: " + str(val))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

client.run("TOKEN")
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: im sorry, what?

Comment: You got an error with a whole lot of lines. Post it all.

Comment: Erro: client ready
'list' object has no attribute 'id'                         'list' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: No, the whole thing.

Comment: I think you should change to **sv = [discord.utils.get(x, id=arg1) for x in client.servers]**

Comment: That dosent work

Comment: What version of discord.py is this?

Comment: The version is 0.16.12

Comment: Oh wow that's **ancient**. Update and refactor your code.

Answer (score 0):

> The version is 0.16.12

According to [ancient tomes](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v0.16.7/api.html?highlight=discord.utils.get#discord.utils.get) this should be the appropriate input for `discord.utils.get`:

```
sv = discord.utils.get(client.servers, id=arg1)
```

Since `client.servers` [is an iterable](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v0.16.7/api.html?highlight=server#discord.Client.servers) it makes no sense to unpack it with `[x for x in client.servers]` and it seems like it is converted into a list when you do that which is giving you your error.

If this doesn't fix the attribute error, update to the latest version and refactor your code, it is extremely outdated and things may be extra buggy as result.

Comment: TypeError: 'Server' object is not iterable

Comment: You have literally one server and that thing is buggy to the point it returns you an edge-case where you don't get a list to iterate with. Try `sv = client.servers`.

Comment: Dosent work, delete_role missing one positional argument 'role'

Comment: What you asked for fixing works, the rest of your code is wrong. Either update what you have or ask a new question.